# Access $('selector').data in functions/objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I access values set by $.data() inside a function or object

```
       $('#timers').data('firsttimer', 100);


    //prints 100
    document.write($('#timers').data('firsttimer'));

    function blah(){
        //Prints nothing
        document.write($('#timers').data('firsttimer'));
    }

blah();
```

See this jsfiddle for easy access to test the code http://jsfiddle.net/JUfd8/

Comment: where are you calling blah() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having trouble with `document.write()` inside the function call for some reason, but it works fine if I use jQuery's `.append()`.

```
function blah(){
    $('body').append($('#timers').data('firsttimer'));
};
```

---

**EDIT:**

Found this stackoverflow question regarding `document.write`:

[Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

An interesting sentence from one of the answers in that post:

***As long as you don't try to use it after the document has loaded, document.write is not inherently evil, in my humble opinion.***

So that may be the key to the trouble (or part of it, anyway).

Comment: In my actual code I do not use document.write but tryting to assign the value to an object. However my problem has correctly enough to do with the order the code is loaded

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is in "document.write()". Try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I believe your document.write is stomping on the DOM in some strange way, wiping out your timers div. Switching both of the document.write calls to alert calls instead (and adding a line to invoke blah()) allowed me to see both alert boxes, both showing the value 100.

```
<div id="timers"></div>
```

js code:

```
$('#timers').data('firsttimer', 100);

//shows 100
alert($('#timers').data('firsttimer'));

function blah(){
  //Prints nothing
  alert($('#timers').data('firsttimer'));
}

blah();
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is not consistent across all browsers. Remember, on jsfiddle this code is already wrapped inside the window load callback since you chose the `onLoad` setting on the left. Once the DOM is loaded, any subsequent changes using `document.write` will replace the entire document.

Here's the relevant text from the [HTML5 specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/apis-in-html-documents.html#document.write) on document.write:

> Unless called from the body of a script element while the document is being parsed, or called on a script-created document, calling this method will clear the current page first, as if document.open() had been called.

Here's how the browsers are behaving on my Mac given this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/JUfd8/5/):

*Chrome and Safari*

Wipes out the document altogether. Even 100 isn't printed. Text nodes by themselves are being ignored here, but when wrapped inside some html tag - they show up. [This code](http://jsfiddle.net/JUfd8/6/) is the same as above with the values wrapped inside `<b>` and `<i>` tags respectively.

*Opera and Firefox*

Wipes out the document, then appends the text node "100undefined". It prints "undefined"  because the node `<div id="timers></div>` does not exist anymore in the new document.

However, it does print "100" the **first time** you call `document.write` on Opera and Firefox

```
document.write($('#timers').data('firsttimer'));
```

because the function argument `$('#timers').data('firsttimer')` is evaluated first and since the original document is intact at this point, we get the value 100, which is then passed to `document.write`, that then recreates the entire document. Therefore, all subsequent calls to fetch the data associated with `#timers` returns undefined.